# Can't open existing semaphore from another process C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, semaphore

I'm trying to get existing semaphore from another process. To create semaphore i used:

```
Semaphore(std::string name, int startState) {
    name = "Global\\" + name;
    Sem = OpenSemaphore(SYNCHRONIZE | SEMAPHORE_MODIFY_STATE, true, (LPCWSTR)name.c_str());
    int s = (startState > 0);
    if (Sem == NULL) {
        Sem = CreateSemaphore(NULL, s, 1, (LPCWSTR)name.c_str());
    }
}
```

In first process semaphore created correctly. GetLastError() returns 0. In second process, OpenSemaphore returns NULL. And GetLastError() returns 2.
I tried to get semaphore by only "name" - without "Global\", but it got the same result. Help please)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you ever feel the need to use C-style casting (like in `(LPCWSTR)name.c_str()`) you should take that as a sign you're doing something wrong.

Like you do here: `std::string` is a ***narrow*** character (i.e. `char`) string, while you use the *wide* characer (`wchar_t`) functions. That means the names won't be what you expect.

If you continue using `std::string` you must use the "ANSI" functions (e.g. `CreateSemaphoreA`). Otherwise switch to `std::wstring` which uses wide characters.

Comment: You are the best! It's first situation, where i stucked with wchars and chars. Thanks a lot!)

Comment: @kepich never use a type-cast to silence a compiler error, unless you *really* know what you are doing. Had you removed the type-casts, the compile would have failed due to type mismatches. Fix the cause of those errors, don't just cover them up.

Answer (score 2):

[@SomeProgrammerDude's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70417468/65863) explains the cause of the error you are seeing (character encoding mismatch).

I just want to point out that after fixing that problem, your code still has a race condition in it.

If you want to open an existing semaphore (or any other kind of named kernel object), and create it if it doesn't exist, then don't bother wasting time opening it, just create it unconditionally, eg:

```
Semaphore(std::string name, int startState) {
    name = "Global\\" + name;
    int s = (startState > 0);
    Sem = CreateSemaphoreA(NULL, s, 1, name.c_str());
}
```

If the object already exists, you will get a handle to the existing object, and the input parameters will be ignored. Otherwise, you will get a handle to a new object initialized with your parameters. `GetLastError()` can be used to tell you whether the object already existed or was created anew, if needed.